# Eclipse RSE connect to a localhost on a remote machine

Tags: python, eclipse, hbase, thrift, eclipse-rse

I'm trying to work with Hbase, thrift, and python on a remote machine(Ubuntu) from Eclise RSE on windows. Everything is working fine but when I'm trying to connect to the localhost I get an error:

```
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:9090
```

If I run this code via ssh terminal on a remote machine, it works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, glob
sys.path.append('gen-py')
sys.path.insert(0, glob.glob('lib/py/build/lib.*')[0])

from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from hbase import Hbase

# Connect to HBase Thrift server
transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(TSocket.TSocket('localhost', 9090))
protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolAccelerated(transport)

# Create and open the client connection
client = Hbase.Client(protocol)
transport.open()

tables = client.getTableNames()

print(tables)

# Do Something

transport.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what localhost means? It means the machine you're running the command on. E.g. if I type http://localhost:8080/ in a browser on my PC then it will call the server running on port 8080 on MY machine.

I'm sure your connection worked fine if you tried connecting to localhost while on the same box. If connecting from a different machine then you'll need to know the IP address or the hostname of the box you're connecting to.